# Name of the theory of lexical semantics that distinguishes consonants by the values "up" and "down"?

Tags: lexical-semantics, cognitive-linguistics, poetry, sound-symbolism

I'm reading "Cognitive interpretation of Czech verse" by Pavel Jiráček about a way to analyze poetry by reading how the consonants, syllables and words conotate "up" and "down".

What is the best broader term for those kind of theories? I guess I need a version for dummies.

Comment: Can you give some examples from Jiráček? If you're talking about the use of pluses and minuses in semantics then that would be feature/componential analysis.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, pure "positive" and "negative" connotations are one of the components Jiráček uses. His positivity/negativity distinction is part of the same dimension as pasivity/activity and lightness/darkness.